# Getting number of retweets of a status

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweets

I want to get number of retweets of a tweet. I write this code

```
$info = $twitteroauth->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/:345469673132945408.json');
$twitteroauth->post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status= This is the status update');
print_r($info);
```

It posts the `This is the status update` message. There is no problem. So there is no problem with `$twitteroauth` object. But it prints an error instead of printing the `$info`

```
[errors] =&gt; Array
    (
        [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
            (
                [message] =&gt; Sorry, that page does not exist
                [code] =&gt; 34
            )

    )
```

[345469673132945408th](https://twitter.com/mcan111/status/345469673132945408) tweet is public and a undeleted tweet. I am using Abraham's library. So how can i get number of retweets of a tweet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$info=$twitter->request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json','GET',array('user_id'=>1234,'count'=>1,'contributer_details'=>true,'exclude_replies'=>true));
$RetweetCount=$info[0]->retweet_count;
```

count=1 implies that we are requiring only one tweet. You can increase it as much as you like, as long as you don't exceed the limit.

Comment: It didn't work. Also, it is not what i am looking for. I want to get retweet number of a spesific tweet, not only last tweet's. Thanks for your try.

Comment: To get the retweet number of a particular tweet with a particular ID you can do the following:                                         $info=$twitter->request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json','GET',array('id'=>123));
$RetweetCount=$info->retweet_count;

Answer (score 0):

For 1.1 api , you can use below url :

statuses/retweeters/ids

and pass your status id in param as second argument : `array('id' => 'status_id')`

so, your final call would be : `$connectionObj->get('statuses/retweeters/ids', array('id' => 'status_id');`

Answer (score 0):

Actually in twitteroauth right way to get amount of retweets or favorites would be

```
$connectionObj->get('statuses/retweets', array('id' => 'status_id');
```